# PCI Cards and Adapters on a laptop

Tags: pci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adaptor that allows me to use a PCI card via a USB connection](https://superuser.com/questions/330979/adaptor-that-allows-me-to-use-a-pci-card-via-a-usb-connection)

I recently purchased a Tascam PCI-822 from eBay. This is a PCI card with a TDIF interface that interfaces with digital audio tape machines.

My question is: not having a desktop PC myself in which to install the card, is there any way that I can hook it up to a laptop? Are there any bridges/adapters out there that mean I could attach the card to either USB or the 34mm/54mm Expresscard slots that you find in some laptops?

I have been reading around a lot and am confused about the compatibility between the different PC card formats. Forgive my ignorance :)

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

[Absolutely](http://www.magma.com/pciexpansion.asp). But don't expect cheap.

Comment: I was about to put an edit mentioning the Magma (and one other system, of what name escapes me) and how they are prohibitively expensive. Should I assume that simple cable converters do not exist? Being different standards, that maybe is the case.

Comment: Power, containment, and bus specification issues must be addressed, which is why a cable-only solution does not exist.

Comment: ow. I'd note a small mini itx system would be a fraction of the price ;)